# Add a line to a file section unless it exists

Tags: linux, bash, patch

I have a file that looks like this:

```
...
%ldirs
(list of line-separated directories)
...
```

With a shell script, I need to add a directory to the list in that file, but only if that directory is not already in the list. Here's the catch: The directory in question must come from a variable $SOME_PATH.

I thought about using the patch utility, but to do that I would have to generate the patch file dynamically to add "+$SOME_PATH". The other problem is that I do not know the "after context" or the line number of "%ldirs", so generating the patch file is problematic.

Is there another option?

Tweaked answer - Thanks to Rob:

```
line=$(grep "$SOME_PATH" /path/to/file)
if [ $? -eq 1 ]
    then
    sed -i "/%ldirs/ a\\$SOME_PATH" /path/to/file
fi
```

Final answer - Thanks to tripleee:

```
fgrep -xq "$SOME_PATH" /path/to/file || sed -i "/%ldirs/ a\\$SOME_PATH" /path/to/file
```

Comment: I hotly debated with myself: stackoverflow, superuser, stackoverflow, superuser. Apparently I got it wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
line=$(grep "$SOME_PATH" %ldirs)
if [ $? -eq 1 ]
    then
    echo "$SOME_PATH" >> %ldirs
fi
```

something like this should work, it worked fine for me. I'm sure there are other ways to write it, too.

```
line=$(grep "$SOME_PATH" /path/to/file)
if [ $? -eq 1 ]
    then
    sed -i 's/%lsdir/%lsdir\n"$SOME_PATH"/' /path/to/file
fi
```

should work. It'll find %lsdir and replace it with %lsdir(newline)$SOME_PATH (not sure if quotes are needed on $SOME_PATH here, pretty sure they aren't)

Comment: `%ldirs` is part of the file contents, not the file name. I think it's like `[section]` in INI files.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. :/ that makes things a bit more difficult then, doesn't it.

Comment: or not. testing something else really quickly.

Comment: Yes, it's just like `[section]` in INI files. Just a wee bit more difficult ;)

Comment: It's close. `$SOME_PATH` is not being expanded in the `sed` line, it's adding it raw.

Comment: try ${SOME_PATH} or replace the single quotes around the sed with double quotes, `sed "s|%lsdir|%lsdir/n$SOME_PATH|"` instead.

Comment: After scrounging the SED docs, I got it. Instead of the `s///` expression, there is an append expression `//a`. See my edit above.

Comment: Btw, the problem for the `s///` expression is that $SOME_PATH contains '/' characters.

Comment: I had problems getting a newline in with append, glad you got it figured out.

Comment: `fgrep -xq "$SOME_PATH" /path/to/file || sed -i 's!%ldirs%&\n'"$SOME_PATH"'!' /path/to/file` ... note the fixed quoting in the `sed` script, and the use of `fgrep -x` to look for the whole line, not a partial match.

Comment: @tripleee Thanks for that. My version didn't work with the -e script argument `#/bin/bash -e` (because of grep returning 1) so I had turned it off. Now I can turn it back on.

Comment: Might still do the erong thing if `SOME_PATH` is present but not in the `%ldirs` section. A more-complex `sed` script will be necessary in that case. It's not that hard, but perhaps this is close enough for the real world already.

Comment: It works for both cases (there or not there). I didn't check if the script will continue past this line as it's the last line in the script; I don't really care if it doesn't.