# sed,awk.grep - add a line to the end of a configuration section if the line doesn't already exist

Tags: linux, sed, awk, grep

I want to edit a file using sed/awk. The file is made up of several configuration sections, like this:

```
SECTION 1 BEGIN
some stuff
SECTION END

SECTION 2 BEGIN
some stuff
some more stuff
important line
SECTION END
```

I want to add `important line` to the end of `SECTION 2` if it doesn't already exist, preferably as a command one liner. I've been looking at the fgrep/sed combo [in this question,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9118553/add-a-line-to-a-file-section-unless-it-exists?answertab=active#tab-top) but I don't quite understand how to adapt it for what I need.

Note: there may be blank lines in the sections.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '
  $0 == "SECTION 2 BEGIN" { inSec2 = 1 } 
  inSec2 && $0 == "important line" { hasImportant = 1 } 
  inSec2 && $0 == "SECTION END" { 
    if (!hasImportant) { print "important line" } 
    inSec2 = 0
  }
  1'
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, that works perfectly. I really need to learn awk, it looks bad ass!

Comment: Good solution. Just small comments. I think instead of `$0 == "..."` the shorter `/^...$/` could be used. And instead of setting `hasImportant` in the second condition the `inSec2` variable could be cleared. So in the third condition the `if` statement become useless. Just `print` the "important line".

Comment: Also "important line" string could be defined once as `awk -vimplin="important line"` (defining in `BEGIN` block is longer). Then `implin` could be used later.

Comment: @TrueY You suggest enough changes that I'd recommend you just post another solution to show an alternate approach.

Comment: Just realised that this needs to go in tcsh, so the multi line command won't work. Can you reformat the command so it is literally on one line?

Comment: @simon surely you can do that yourself!? If you are using `tcsh` and really don't have `bash` you also need to change `(!hasImportant)` to `(hasImportant==0)`.

Comment: @sudo_O: ??? The if is inside the awk script. It is nothing to do with bash. Isn't it?

Comment: @TrueY Not true, using `!` with `csh` can be a pain http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Csh.html#uh-1

Comment: @simon Sorry, I don't know really know the details of scripting in tcsh. If you can't figure it out, just save what I've given in my answer in a file, stick `#! /bin/sh` at the top, make it executable with `chmod` (or whatever the tcsh equivalent is), and pipe your text through it.

Comment: @sudo_O: Ok, you may be right. Based on the doc, `\!` could work. But anyway the whole `hasImportant` stuff could be skipped.

Comment: @TrueY yes you could also do that but then you break the script with `bash` so it is safer to be explicit here `(hasImportant==0)`.

Comment: Unfortunately my situation is this: We need to edit a config file on some very locked down hardware appliances that run some variant of redhat/centos. We want to be able to configure these devices by pasting a configuration into an SSH session. The default shell is tsch, we can run sh but I would rather not.

Answer (score 3):

Based on Michael's solution there is a one-liner:

```
awk -vline="important line" '/^SECTION 2 BEGIN$/{f=1}f&&$0==line{f=0}f&&/^SECTION END$/{print line;f=0}1'<<EOT
SECTION 1 BEGIN
some stuff
SECTION END

SECTION 2 BEGIN
some stuff
some more stuff
SECTION END

SECTION 2 BEGIN
some stuff
some more stuff
important line
SECTION END

SECTION 3 BEGIN
oops
SECTION END
EOT
```

Output:

```
SECTION 1 BEGIN
some stuff
SECTION END

SECTION 2 BEGIN
some stuff
some more stuff
important line
SECTION END

SECTION 2 BEGIN
some stuff
some more stuff
important line
SECTION END

SECTION 3 BEGIN
oops
SECTION END
```

Comment: @simon: It is just the "here is the document". Same as if You write the lines between the `awk` and the last `EOT` line to a file and You do a `<filename` to awk. It is easy to show examples in one...