# Change a configuration variable or add it if it does not exist using sed/awk/grep

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I have a configuration file located at `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` that ***may or may not*** include a configuration line that sets `PermitRootLogin`.

```
PermitRootLogin yes
```

My goal is to either change this value to something I know is correct (regardless of the current value), or to add the configuration line to the end of the file if the configuration value is not currently set in the file.

In other words, I would like a command line one-liner (or as few lines as possible) to do the following:

***If a line that begins with `PermitRootLogin` followed by a space or tab exists, replace the entire line with `PermitRootLogin no`. Otherwise, add the line `PermitRootLogin no` to the end of the file.***

I want to this to work on the command line (Bash on Linux) so sed, awk, and grep can be used.

I know I can do half of my requirement (if it exists, replace it) with

```
sed -i 's/^PermitRootLogin[ \t].*$/PermitRootLogin no/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

If this could be modified to add the line if there was no match, that would work for me.

[sed,awk.grep - add a line to the end of a configuration section if the line doesn't already exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16102213/sed-awk-grep-add-a-line-to-the-end-of-a-configuration-section-if-the-line-does) is close as well but does not fulfill  my full requirement.

---

**Edit: Maintaining the position of a set configuration variable in the file is important to me.** The variables are defined in a certain logical order that is useful to human editors. Since this file may be edited by hand in the future, I want to maintain the order. A solution that simply deletes the configuration variable and adds it to the end does not fit my requirements. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace `sed` bu this `awk`:

```
awk '/^PermitRootLogin/ {
   found=1;
   sub(/^PermitRootLogin[[:blank:]]+.*$/, "PermitRootLogin no")
}
1; 
END {
   if (!found)
      print "PermitRootLogin no"
}' file
```

Comment: For some reason it only replaces when I take `[[:blank:]]` from your code and replace  with `[ \t]`. Do you have any idea why that might be? I'm using Debian 8 Jessie so I imagine awk is up to date.

Comment: `[[:blank:]]` usually means `[ \t]`. You can use `[ \t]` if that works better for you in your awk

Comment: Yes, I found that in the docs. I'm not sure why it's not working but it certainly should. Anyway, thanks for the superb answer :)

Answer (score 2):

This could be done with [`sed`](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Other-Commands.html#Other-Commands) as well:

Usually, these conf files do not have any hard-requirement about the sequence of options. At least `sshd_config` doesn't have such requirement.

Thus, this `sed` should work just fine:

```
sed '/PermitRootLogin/d; ${p;s/.*/PermitRootLogin yes/}' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

If you want to retain the line position in the file, use below command.

```
sed '1{p;s/.*/PermitRootLogin yes/;h;d;};/^PermitRootLogin/{g;p;s/.*//;h;d;};$G' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

After you've satisfied with the output, add the `-i` flag to sed command to perform in-place replacement.

Answer (score 1):

You can add or override default ssh configuration in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/` without messing with default `sshd_config`

```bash
# Override sshd configuration
cat << EOF | sudo tee /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/override.conf
PermitRootLogin no
PasswordAuthentication no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
EOF

# Restart sshd service
sudo systemctl restart sshd
```